# D3 recalculate arrowhead position based on node size

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am facing two visual problems with the given D3 forced graph.

1. The last inch of each link is still visible. The arrowhead should end exactly at the node edge, which is the case, but the red link underneath is visible. I could adjust the link stroke-width or the arrow size but actually do not want to change those attributes.

[image]

2. The radius of a node increases on a mouseenter event. If node size increases, the arrowhead is out of position and does not end on the node endge anymore. I assume I need to adjust the tick function, but do not find a proper starting point.

[image]

I appreciate any link, hint, help which gets me closer to the result.

```js
        var width = window.innerWidth,
            height = window.innerHeight;

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function(event) {
                svg.attr("transform", event.transform)
            }))
            .append("g")

        ////////////////////////
        // outer force layout

        var data = {
            "nodes":[
                { "id": "A" }, 
                { "id": "B" },
                { "id": "C" },
            ],
            "links": [
                { "source": "A", "target": "B"},
                { "source": "B", "target": "C"},
                { "source": "C", "target": "A"}
            ]
        };

        var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
            .force("size", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
            .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-1000))
            .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) { return d.id }).distance(250))

        svg.append("defs").append("marker")
            .attr('id', 'arrowhead')
            .attr('viewBox', '-0 -5 10 10')
            .attr("refX", 23.5)
            .attr("refY", 0)
            .attr('orient', 'auto')
            .attr('markerWidth', 10)
            .attr('markerHeight', 10)
            .attr("orient", "auto")
            .append('svg:path')
            .attr('d', 'M 0,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5')
            .attr('fill', '#999')
            .style('stroke', 'none');

        var links = svg.selectAll(".links")
            .data(data.links)
            .join("line")
            .attr("stroke", "red")
            .attr("stroke-width", 3)
            .attr("marker-end", "url(#arrowhead)")
   
        var nodes = svg.selectAll("g.outer")
            .data(data.nodes, function (d) { return d.id; })
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "outer")
            .attr("id", function (d) { return d.id; })
            .call(d3.drag()
                .on("start", dragStarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragEnded)
            );

        nodes
            .append("circle")
            .style("fill", "lightgrey")
            .style("stroke", "blue")
            .attr("r", 40)
            .on("mouseenter", function() {
                d3.select(this)
                    .transition()
                        .duration(250)
                            .attr("r", 40 * 1.3)
                            .attr("fill", "blue")
            })
            .on("mouseleave", function() {
                d3.select(this)
                    .transition()
                        .duration(250)
                            .attr("r", 40)
                            .attr("fill", "lightgrey")
            })            

        simulation
            .nodes(data.nodes)
            .on("tick", tick)

        simulation
            .force("link")
            .links(data.links)


            
        function tick() {
            links
                .attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
                .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
                .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
                .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });
                

            nodes
                .attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x}, ${d.y})`);
        }

        function dragStarted(event, d) {
            if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
            d.fx = d.x;
            d.fy = d.y;
        }

        function dragged(event, d) {
            d.fx = event.x;
            d.fy = event.y;
        }

        function dragEnded(event, d) {
            if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
            d.fx = null;
            d.fy = null;
        }
```

```css
    body {
        background: whitesmoke,´;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>D3v7</title>
    <!-- d3.js framework -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js"></script>
</head>



<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think you could reinvent your arrow-heads so it would in reality be thicker than currently, the shape would look similarly, but it would have some margins at both sides having the background color. I'm not sure how to do that in svg, but intuitively this could be a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## solution

at the moment I can think of two solutions.

1. calculate each `<path(.links)/>` vector and subtract with extended circle radius
2. give offset to each `<marker />`

personally I've chosen the 2nd solution; it requires less computation and easier to understand.

### 1. give each links custom arrowhead

add separate arrowheads for each link because it seems individual offset is not supported by svg path.

```js
            // add custom arrowheads for each link
            // to avoid exhaustive computations
            svg.append("defs").selectAll('marker')
                .data(data.links)
                .join("marker")
                .attr('id', d => `arrowhead-target-${d.target}`)
// ...
        var links = svg.selectAll(".links")
            .data(data.links)
            .join("line")
            .attr("stroke", "red")
            .attr("stroke-width", 3)
            .attr("marker-end", d => `url(#arrowhead-target-${d.target})`)
            // add source and target so that it can be traced back
```

### 2. extend, subtract each individual marker's offset with mouseevent

the offset for `<marker />` is applied with `.refX, .refY` attributes, as noted in [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/refX)

```js
        nodes
            .append("circle")
            .style("fill", "lightgrey")
            .style("stroke", "blue")
            .attr("r", 40)
            .on("mouseenter", function(ev, d) {
               // trace back to custom arrowhead with given id
                const arrowHead = d3.select(`#arrowhead-target-${d.id}`)
               arrowHead.transition().duration(250).attr('refX', 40)
                d3.select(this)
                    .transition()
                        .duration(250)
                            .attr("r", 40 * 1.3)
                            .attr("fill", "blue")
            })
            .on("mouseleave", function(ev, d) {
                const arrowHead = d3.select(`#arrowhead-target-${d.id}`)
               arrowHead.transition().duration(250).attr('refX', 23.5)
                d3.select(this)
                    .transition()
                        .duration(250)
                            .attr("r", 40)
                            .attr("fill", "lightgrey")
            })
```

Try run the code below. The size of extension and subtraction is purposefully exaggerated so that you can see the difference.

```js
var width = window.innerWidth,
            height = window.innerHeight;

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function(event) {
                svg.attr("transform", event.transform)
            }))
            .append("g")

        ////////////////////////
        // outer force layout

        var data = {
            "nodes":[
                { "id": "A" }, 
                { "id": "B" },
                { "id": "C" },
            ],
            "links": [
                { "source": "A", "target": "B"},
                { "source": "B", "target": "C"},
                { "source": "C", "target": "A"}
            ]
        };

        var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
            .force("size", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
            .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-1000))
            .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) { return d.id }).distance(250))
        // add custom arrowheads for each link
        // to avoid exhaustive computations
        svg.append("defs").selectAll('marker')
            .data(data.links)
            .join("marker")
            .attr('id', d => `arrowhead-target-${d.target}`)
            .attr('viewBox', '-0 -5 10 10')
            .attr("refX", 23.5)
            .attr("refY", 0)
            .attr('orient', 'auto')
            .attr('markerWidth', 10)
            .attr('markerHeight', 10)
            .attr("orient", "auto")
            .append('svg:path')
            .attr('d', 'M 0,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5')
            .attr('fill', '#999')
            .style('stroke', 'none');

        var links = svg.selectAll(".links")
            .data(data.links)
            .join("line")
            .attr("stroke", "red")
            .attr("stroke-width", 3)
            .attr("marker-end", d => `url(#arrowhead-target-${d.target})`)
            // add source and target so that it can be traced back
            .attr('data-source', d => d.source)
            .attr('data-target', d => d.target)
   
        var nodes = svg.selectAll("g.outer")
            .data(data.nodes, function (d) { return d.id; })
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "outer")
            .attr("id", function (d) { return d.id; })
            .call(d3.drag()
                .on("start", dragStarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragEnded)
            );

        nodes
            .append("circle")
            .style("fill", "lightgrey")
            .style("stroke", "blue")
            .attr("r", 40)
            .on("mouseenter", function(ev, d) {
               // trace back to custom arrowhead with given id
                const arrowHead = d3.select(`#arrowhead-target-${d.id}`)
               arrowHead.transition().duration(250).attr('refX', 40)
                d3.select(this)
                    .transition()
                        .duration(250)
                            .attr("r", 40 * 1.3)
                            .attr("fill", "blue")
            })
            .on("mouseleave", function(ev, d) {
                const arrowHead = d3.select(`#arrowhead-target-${d.id}`)
               arrowHead.transition().duration(250).attr('refX', 23.5)
                d3.select(this)
                    .transition()
                        .duration(250)
                            .attr("r", 40)
                            .attr("fill", "lightgrey")
            })            

        simulation
            .nodes(data.nodes)
            .on("tick", tick)

        simulation
            .force("link")
            .links(data.links)


            
        function tick() {
            links
                .attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
                .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
                .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
                .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });
                

            nodes
                .attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x}, ${d.y})`);
        }

        function dragStarted(event, d) {
            if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
            d.fx = d.x;
            d.fy = d.y;
        }

        function dragged(event, d) {
            d.fx = event.x;
            d.fy = event.y;
        }

        function dragEnded(event, d) {
            if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
            d.fx = null;
            d.fy = null;
        }
```

```css
body {
        background: whitesmoke,´;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>D3v7</title>
    <!-- d3.js framework -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js"></script>
</head>



<body>

</body>

</html>
```